# MYSQL LIKE query working in MYSQL database but in Spring JPA

Tags: mysql, spring, database, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a query to search for a particular row using the like operator in MYSQL, it runs perfectly on mysql workbench, but i cant seem to make it run on Spring's JPA using nativequery.
The query in MYSQL is:

```
SELECT * FROM product where PRODUCT_ID LIKE '33__:modelId00000000';
```

It works when i tested it in workbench:

[image]

Wherein im using wildcards to find all products that contains a certain string in the correct character position. The productId starts with 33, followed by 0-100 and then the model id, So %:modelId% will not work here. This is my JPA query right now, but it returns null.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM product where PRODUCT_ID LIKE '33__:modelId00000000'", nativeQuery = true)
List<Product> getProductByModelId(String modelId);
```

What is allowed to be returned, if for example modelId is "99" in this case:

- 3300**99**00000000
- 3301**99**00000000
- 3302**99**00000000
- 3303**99**00000000
- 3355**99**00000000
- 3389**99**00000000
- 3399**99**00000000

Comment: That simply won't work as there is no `:modelId` property in your query. You have a constant in your query containing `:modelId` but that isn't used as query attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, you can try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM product where PRODUCT_ID LIKE CONCAT('33%',:modelId,'00000000')
```

But since I'm not familiar with JPA I'm not sure if this query is safe from MySQL injection or not.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6fa0548bca356e32ad2dc3fc952085c3)

Comment: Works perfectly, im sanitizing the data so this should be safe.